# How do I register IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries as a linked server provider in SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange, linked-server

I have connected to a DB2 database on our AS400 through SQL Server 2005 (linked server) using the IBMDA400 (OLEDB) provider. However, I recently discovered that I can connect my .Net apps using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll provider so I would like to connect to the AS400 using my IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries provider instead. However, the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries provider is not in my list of options to connect with when trying to set up my linked server. How do I register this as a provider?

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with your OLE DB provider ? Why do you want to use .NET provider?

As far as I know a **linked server requires an OLE DB provider to work with iSeries DB2 database and there is no option to use .NET instead**. IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries provider allows .NET managed programs to access the iSeries database files using SQL.

Have a look on this:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaik/rzaikdotnetprovider.htm

You can try to install IBM iSeries Access for Windows and Programmer's Toolkik after that, but I would be surprise if you can see DB2 iSeries .NET provider on the provider list in SQL Server.

Do you have any performance issues or something doesn't work with OLE DB?

Comment: The problem with my OLE DB provider is that it is slow when it is pulling money from SQL Server to DB2. Since SQL Server 2005 & 2008 are more geared towards .Net, I wanted to try the DB2 .Net specific driver through SQL Server. If it absolutely cannot be done, then I will close this question but I was looking for an absolute, yes or no. Also, I did install the programmer's toolkit and it didn't add anything but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't do anything with iSeries at the moment so my knowledge isn't really up to date but I worked for more than 5 years with AS400 (from version V3R2 to V5R3) and only performance issues I had was with ODBC. I am quite sure you need OLE DB provider but if you have a .NET Provider, you can implement CLR functions that access the data on iSeries. Maybe you use some convert function that slows the performance down.